# Create Record quick action is not visible for non-admin users

Tags: custom-object, opportunity, permissions, profile, quickaction

I have a custom quick action using which users can create contract from opportunity record page.

Now, the issue here is that, all the non-admin users are not able to access the quick action. But the users have CRED access to both the objects along with recordtype access.

Can anyone suggest me if the resolution if I'm missing anything here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are the non-admin users assigned a different page layout?

There's the possibility that you will need to add the quick action to the layouts used by those non-admin users.

Comment: Users are assigned with required page layout for the record type that we are using. Users also have the record type assigned to their profiles and permission sets and even then, they are not able to view the required quick action

Answer (score 0):

Below are check points.

- Check if System Admin profile has a default record type of master when you have custom record type and don’t assign actions to the master record type.  The Master record type is a placeholder record type that’s assigned when your organization is created.
- See if lookup field of parent object has 'Read/Write' permission on non-admin user.
- 'Allow Access to Customized Actions' on profile is checked.

Review steps mentioned [Unable to see global or quick actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000340216&type=1) and [Quick Action considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.actions_considerations.htm&type=5).

Thanks

Comment: Users are assigned with required page layout for the record type that we are using. Users also have the record type assigned to their profiles and permission sets and even then, they are not able to view the required quick action.